# How to change context-root for enterprise application (.ear) in weblogic

Tags: java, weblogic, ear, weblogic-10.x, application.xml

We have third party web based enterprise application, which is deployed on weblogic server and can be accessible using

```
http://hostname:port/myApp
```

But, due to some reason, we wanted to change `context-root` for this application, so that it must be **ONLY** accessible using

```
http://hostname:port/newApp
```

So, to achieve this, we tried changing `application.xml`

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'utf-8'?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/application_1_4.xsd" version="1.4">
   <display-name>myApp</display-name>
   <module>
         <web>
            <web-uri>myApp.war</web-uri>
            <context-root>newApp</context-root>  // changed from myApp to newApp
         </web>
   </module>
</application>
```

But, while deploying this application on weblogic server, we are getting following error.

```
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: The application myApp contains a SubDeploymentMBean with a name myApp however there is no module in the application with that URI or context-root.
```

On the other hand, if we keep both `context-root` as shown below `application.xml` file, then it gets deployed successfully and also able to access application using both context-root.

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'utf-8'?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/application_1_4.xsd" version="1.4">
   <display-name>myApp</display-name>
   <module>
         <web>
            <web-uri>myApp.war</web-uri>
            <context-root>newApp</context-root>  // changed from myApp to newApp
         </web>
   </module>
   <module>
         <web>
            <web-uri>myApp.war</web-uri>
            <context-root>myApp</context-root>
         </web>
   </module>
</application>
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue ? Let me know, if additional information required.

**==Edited==**

I have added `weblogic.xml` file, but not sure, what I suppose to change in this file as pointed by @Hououin Kyouma in his/her answer.

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'US-ASCII'?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app">
   <session-descriptor> 
      <cookie-path>/myApp</cookie-path> 
   </session-descriptor>
   <container-descriptor>
       <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
   </container-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the context root in the weblogic.xml?
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/webapp/weblogic_xml.html#1073750

EDIT
Trying adding it like mentioned in this 
https://community.oracle.com/thread/747158

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'US-ASCII'?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app">
 <context-root>/newApp</context-root>
<session-descriptor> 
  <cookie-path>/newApp</cookie-path> 
</session-descriptor>
<container-descriptor>
   <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
</container-descriptor>
```

Comment: how can we change context-root value in weblogic.xml ? I have updated my weblogic.xml file on my post.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but I'm still getting same error (mentioned in my post)

Comment: Do youi get the error when you deploy the application?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define a context root with a differently named war file in the application.xml

```
<module>
    <web>
        <web-uri>myApp.war</web-uri>
        <context-root>newApp</context-root>  // changed from myApp to newApp
    </web>
</module>
```

You must change above to

```
<module>
    <web>
        <web-uri>newApp.war</web-uri>    // changed from myApp to newApp
        <context-root>newApp</context-root>  
    </web>
</module>
```

You need to create the war with the new name. You will still need to change the weblogic.xml in the new war file, but as long as this question goes, above is what you need to do.